# HIPAA compliant PHP/MySQL application

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, amazon-web-services, hipaa

I'm working on a PHP/MySQL application that must be HIPAA compliant. From what I've read, any personal data that may identify someone or any medical information must be 256-bit encrypted both at rest and in transit. I'm trying to figure out what the most efficient approach to this is.

I am using Amazon Web Services and I thought of using SSL encryption for both HTTP and database requests to protect data in transit. As for data at rest, I thought of compiling a custom MySQL server with AES 256 in order to use AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT -- but would I then have to store an IV for each field I encrypt? Otherwise, doing encryption/decryption within the application itself would take too long and querying the database would be hell.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you just [use SSL to connect to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html) and then encrypt the database files at the storage level, rather than MySQL? *Any thoughts?* Beyond this, engage a consultant.

Comment: I've just answered [a question about medical information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012010/472495) in relation to asymmetric encryption, which may be of interest. If you are using symmetric encryption, would an IV per row be a good trade-off? One IV per field per row sounds rather onerous, imo. (Note I am not au fait with HIPAA requirements).

Comment: Does HIPAA specify whether you must use symmetric or asymmetric encryption? However about disk-level encryption as per ta.speot.is's suggestion - is that permitted? Bear in mind that if your web server is compromised, both disk-level encryption and symmetric encryption won't prevent your data from being stolen.

Answer (score 2):

HIPAA does not actually require that your ePHI be encrypted "at-rest" when stored in your MySQL database, as long as it is isolated so that no unauthorised people can access it.

That said, it is generally always better to have your data encrypted at rest, if possible, as that prevents a breach from happening should the data be compromised.

Read in detail about HIPAA compliance for mySQL and encryption options here (I have no relationship with this website):

https://luxsci.com/blog/encryption-and-auditing-for-mysql-databases-under-hipaa.html